# Flask send_file() return status 200 but doesn't return anything

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to download a PDF file using the send_file method, the request is executed successfully and returns code 200, but nothing is downloaded. I used the same procedure that I have in another project running, I don't know what is going wrong.

This is the code I am trying to run

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Solicitar firma de usuario - By Parzibyte</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Firmar a continuación:</p>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <br>
    <button id="btnLimpiar">Limpiar</button>
    <button id="btnDescargar">Descargar</button>
    <button id="btnGenerarDocumento">Pasar a documento</button>
    <br>
    <a href="https://parzibyte.me/blog">By Parzibyte</a>
    <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        $btnDescargar.onclick = async () => {
    // Convertir la imagen a Base64 y ponerlo en el enlace
    const data = $canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("imagen", data);
    const respuestaHttp = await fetch("{{url_for('generar')}}", {
      method: "POST",
      body: fd,
    });
    //const nombreImagenSubida = await JSON.parse(respuestaHttp);
    //console.log("La imagen ha sido enviada y tiene el nombre de: " + nombreImagenSubida);
  };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, send_file, url_for, request
from generar_firma import convertir_a_imagen
from escribirExcel import firmar_excel
from deExcelaPDF import convertir_excel_a_pdf
import time
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ''

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/api/generar', methods=["GET","POST"])
def generar():
    #La firma llega en forma de string y la recibo aca
    image_string = request.form['imagen']
    #Se la paso a un metodo del modulo gener_firma, que la convierte de string a base64
    #y de base64 a png
    #En firma solamente guardo el nombre del archivo para despues buscarlo
    firma = convertir_a_imagen(image_string)
    #Llamo a este metodo de escribirExcel.py que se encarga de firmar el Excel
    #esto me devuelve la ruta del excel firmado
    nombre_excel_firmado = firmar_excel(firma)
    print(f'nombre_excel_firmado: {nombre_excel_firmado}')
    #paso la ruta del excel firmado a un metodo del modulo deExcelaPDF
    filename = convertir_excel_a_pdf(nombre_excel_firmado)
    directorio = os.path.join(app.root_path)
    print(f'ruta_pdf: {directorio}\{filename}')
    return send_file(path_or_file=directorio+'\\'+filename, as_attachment=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
    #app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8383')
```

The console output

```
ruta_pdf: C:\app-flask\pruebaFirmada.pdf
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2022 12:20:30] "POST /api/generar HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The PDF exists in the directory indicated by the print in console.

Comment: pretty sure this is a duplicate of the question for which this is the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978303/42346

Comment: the issue is that the template stuff can't be processed inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand the error, however I can't understand how to implement it in my project.

Comment: @mechanical_meat I don't understand what is the point of saying it's a duplicate and closing the question without warning, that doesn't solve anything

Comment: the answer i linked has a solution, how is that not solving anything?